# Restrict Date parser in certain cases

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, text-mining, stanford-nlp

Sorry if the title wasn't self-explanatory. Here is a detailed version.

I created a data parser to parse dates from resumes. The ultimate goal is to find how many years of work experience a candidate has "based on the resume." The parser can catch dates in all formats like:

1. MM/DD/YY - MM/DD/YY
2. MM/DD/YYYY - MM/DD/YYYY
3. Apr 09 - Jul 11
4. 03/09 - 07/11
5. 2007 - 2010
   etc.

The way in which the parser works is it first extracts all the dates and then converts them into "Apr 2009 - Jul 2011" format (the difference is, whatever format the date is written in the resume, it will be converted like this regardless) and be stored in a **list**

The Next step after conversion of all the dates is, sorting them based on the "last four" characters of each element. For eg: if the parsed dates are

```
["Apr 2009 - Jul 2011", "Jan 2014 - Oct 2018", "Feb 2013 - Jun 2014", "Nov 2018 - Aug 2021", "Mar 2010 - Sep 2012", "Jan 2005 - Mar 2008"]
```

The last four "Apr 2009 - Jul 2011" is **2011**, likewise the whole list is sorted (descending order) based on this criteria. So the list now becomes like this:

```
["Nov 2018 - Aug 2021", "Jan 2014 - Oct 2018", "Feb 2013 - Jun 2014", "Mar 2010 - Sep 2012", "Apr 2009 - Jul 2011","Jan 2005 - Mar 2008"]
```

And the total number of years, months are calculated by just summing the dates. I also ignore overlapping dates. In the above case if u notice the dates **"Mar 2010 - Sep 2012"** & **"Apr 2009 - Jul 2011"** have overlapping months. So only **"Mar 2010 - Sep 2012"** is considered and **"Apr 2009 - Jul 2011"** is discarded.

Now coming to the issue I am facing, sometimes in CVs people tend to mention the software they have used in the past. (Un)fortunately, some of that software come along with their "year as version" For eg: **SQL Server 2005 2008** or **Windows Server 2010 - 2011** etc.

What's happening is.. my date parser is catching these years too. Luckily, sometime's these dates are discarded due to overlapping.
Unfortunately, sometimes **these dates** are being considered and actual dates which are supposed to be considered, are being discarded due to overlapping with the **versions**.

I can't think of any generalized way(atleast not yet) to avoid catching the "year as version" pattern. Can someone help me out on this? How can I prevent my parser from catching such patterns?

**TIA.**

Comment: I am not sure how you've structured your parser, but to me this seems easiest to achieve by applying a scoping step after the parsing to only select the dates that occur in the 'work experience' section, also because there seems nothing distinctly different between the dates in the work experience vs technology case.

Comment: @Oxbowerce these "years as versions" are also inside the work-experience section :/